# httpd, проблема с конфигурированием mbstring.internal_encoding для отдельного виртуалхоста

Tags: centos, httpd

Машина на CentOS. 
На ней поднят httpd, на котором крутятся два сайта на битриксе.

Проблема в том, что один сайт работает в UTF-8, а другой в cp1251, дефолтная кодировка сервера UTF-8. 
Соответственно, из-за конфликта кодировки тот сайт, что на cp1251 выкидывает ошибки при тестах:

> Ошибка! Сайт работает в однобайтовой кодировке, настройки mbstring:
>   mbstring.func_overload=2 mbstring.internal_encoding=utf-8 требуется:
>   mbstring.internal_encoding=cp1251

Т.к. PHP уже давно не даёт возможности конфигурировать параметры mbstring из htaccess, попытался напрямую прописать конфиг mbstring в параметры виртуалхоста. В итоге, httpd просто не запустился.
Конфиг виртуалхоста:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    ServerName main
    ServerAlias main
    DocumentRoot /var/www/parts/data/www/main
    ServerAdmin webmaster@main
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    AddDefaultCharset off
    SuexecUserGroup parts parts
    CustomLog /var/www/httpd-logs/main.access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/www/httpd-logs/main.error.log
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/parts/data/www/main/cgi-bin/
    <FilesMatch "\.ph(p[3-5]?|tml)$">
        SetHandler fcgid-script
        FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-bin-isp-php70/main/php
    </FilesMatch>
    SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
</VirtualHost>
<Directory /var/www/parts/data/www/main>
    Options +Includes +ExecCGI
    mbstring.func_overload 0
    mbstring.internal_encoding=cp1251
</Directory>
```

Собственно, какие варианты решения проблемы можете предложить? Или же я где-то допустил ошибку? 
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

UPD. сервер запустился. Но теперь на все запросы отвечает только 502 ошибкой.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй задать значения в .htaccess для каждого сайта свой вариант:

```
php_value mbstring.func_overload 2

php_value mbstring.internal_encoding UTF-8
```

Comment: Значение конфигураций mbstring игнорируется из htaccess

Answer (score 0):

В общем, в итоге концепции маленько поменялись и проблема решилась соедующим образом:  маленько пересобрали конфиги вебсервера, в итоге для каждого виртуалхоста подрубается свой конфиг php.ini, соответственно, надобность в костылях отпала и теперь спокойно конфигурируем все для каждого проекта отдельно.